# How can i imbibe the app calendar on my APP [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, eventkit

I have an iOS app which loads the APP Calendar from an iPad/iPhone. I use the scheme url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I want show the calendar in a part of my view because I want to keep using my application, but when I push the calendar, it takes all the screen.

Can someone say me how to imbibe the calendar?

I took this way cause I need load a Gmail calendar on my app, then I want to use `Eventkit` to add or delete some events.

With `Eventkit` you can not create a calendar right?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to embed the default calendar view in your app. However, you could use a [third party library replicating the calendar application](https://github.com/search?q=ios%20calendar&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults).

Regarding your "create calendar" question: this is possible. [Here is an example](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/05/creating-and-deleting-calendars-in-ios/) of how to do it.

Comment: i need to show the calendar on my screen, not just to manage the data. This tutorial teach you to manage the data but not how to show the calendar with the data. Can u recommend me a good and easy tutorial for that? thanks--- EDIT: I didnt see the third pary libraries, can u recommend me some easy and good library for calendars? there are so many calendars. Sorry for that but im new on ios and im learning

Comment: Just visit the first link - there are various projects providing calendar views.

Comment: "good" totally depends on what you would like to do. Just browse through them and pick the one that fits your needs.

Comment: I'm doing it. Thanks for your answers.